# Java MongoDB : updating multiple documents at a time

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a following schema

```
Id:
date_created:
vars: {
      NAME:
      VALUE:
      EDITABLE:
      .....

}
```

- By definition `Id` is `unique` and could be like `A, B, C, AA, AB, ....`
- I have over a million documents like these, all `unique` documents
- Lets say I want to update `VALUE` in `vars` of subset of `documents` which qualify the `Id` provided to me as a `list`.

Using the [api](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.8.0/), I am not sure which api I can use to do multiple document updates qualifying the criteria where `{Id: {$in: [A, B, X, Y, ...]}}`

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Use [this version](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.8.0/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#update%28com.mongodb.DBObject,%20com.mongodb.DBObject,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) of the `update` method and set the `multi` parameter to true.  Otherwise the update will only be applied to the first matched document.